# Uncaught TypeError: "text.toLowerCase() Is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

When I run the below code, I am getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: text.toLowerCase is not a function

```
    const getVisibleExpenses = (expenses, { text, sortBy, startDate, 
      endDate }) => {
    return expenses.filter((expense) => {
    const startDateMatch = typeof startDate !== 'number' || 
      expense.createdAt >= startDate;
    const endDateMatch = typeof endDate !== 'number' || expense.createdAt 
      <= endDate;
    const textMatch = 
      expense.description.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase());

    return startDateMatch && endDateMatch && textMatch;
  });
};
```

I cannot figure out what is going wrong.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is "text"?

Comment: sounds like expense.description is not a string. Are you sure the error is thrown at that line? the error says `text.toLowerCase` rather than `expense.description.toLowerCase`. In any case. that error specifically is thrown whenever `text` is not instance of string.

Comment: `var text; (text || '').toLowerCase()`

Comment: toLowerCase() work only with string

Comment: @briosheje: Read the whole line

Comment: You've posted more code, but it's still not a [MCVE]. There's no way we can put it into our browsers and reproduce your problem - almost all of the variables are missing definitions.

Comment: Try running this by itself `var text = undefined; var lc = text.toLowerCase(); ` Look familiar?

Comment: My idea is that `text` is not what you think it is. `console.log(text);` inside the inner function body, before `textMatch`.

Comment: Okay guys thanks we have 500 comments and answers saying the same thing now, no need for more

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think `text` isn't actually text.

Comment: @KevinB: Personally I was wondering whether the variable `text` holds something that isn't a string.

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case the issue was that in dropdown control I changed name of valueField and for toLowerCase() I still used the old name.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify what the definition of `text` is. From the error message, assuming `text` holds an object it does not have the method `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: text is defined, let me post the rest of the code the code (I should have in the first place).

Comment: Also if text is of type number it does not have the method toLowerCase()